# Show Image on UISplitViewController

Tags: swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm a newbie in SWIFT and I do some examples application.

The only thing that I can not get worked is to get my Image displayed on Detail Scene (DetailViewController).

On my MasterViewController file I have this to get my `multiData` file:

```
...

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showData" {

        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController

            controller.detailItem = self.multiData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}

// Here I get my multiData
func createData() {

    var first: [Dictionary<String,String>] = []
    var second: [Dictionary<String,String>] = []

    dataSections = ["First Data", "Second Data"]

    first.append(["name": "someName", "image": "somePngFile", "someData": "someText"])        
    second.append(["name": "someName", "image": "somePngFile", "someData": "someText"])

    multiData = [first, second]
}
```

DetailViewController:

```
...

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!    
@IBOutlet weak var text: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

...

func configureView() {        

    if let detail = self.detailItem {

        if let labelTitle = label {

            labelTitle.text = detail["name"] as! String!
        }

        if let textData = text {

            textData.text = detail["someData"] as! String!
        }

        // This obvious doesn't work
        if let imageFile = image {

            imageFile.image = detail["image"] as! UIImage!
        }
    }
}
```

So, my question is how can I get the Image from `detail["image"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the image contained in `detail["image"]` is in your application Bundle (i.e.: not an image from an `HTTP` URL). So, you should use the [`init(named:)` constructor from `UIImage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:) to load your image. Something like that:

```
if let myImage = UIImage(named: detail["image"]) {
    myImageView.image = myImage
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is, also, your code with a better management of optionals and casts in `configureView`:

```
func configureView() {
    if let detail = self.detailItem {

        if let labelTitle = detail["name"] as? String {
            myLabel.text = labelTitle
        }

        if let textViewContent = detail["someData"] as? String {
            myTextView.text = textViewContent
        }

        if let myImageName = detail["image"] as? String {
            if let myImage = UIImage(named: myImageName) {
                myImageView.image = myImage
            }
        }
    }
}
```